# index single cap letters with Sphinx?

Tags: sphinx

It appears sphinx is not indexing single lettes, especially 'a' however I need it to at very least index capital A e.g. 'Class A'. My  min_word_len = 1 but that still makes no difference. Is there a way to force it to index 'A'?

Comment: Are you using a stop word list? "A" is an English word common enough to appear in this.

Comment: It should work with min_word_len =1 . But from your other posts you seem to have a pretty complicated setup, so possibly some other setting is interfering.